# Why are Android ELF files different?

Tags: linux

When I try to run a x64 ELF file which was build for Android on my desktop PC I get a "file not found" error.

I think that's normal because Android ELF files aren't compatible to normal ELF files.

What is the reason behind this?

Comment: The standard libraries on Android are a bit different. Have you checked the linked libraries of the executable via `ldd`?

Comment: Build a statically linked program and it'll work on both sides. For dynamically linked binaries/libraries a linker is required which links and loads the libraries required by the executed program. Linker path is hard-coded in the program. It is `/system/bin/linker` in case of Android (when built with NDK), while something like `/lib/ld.so` in case of common Linux distros (when built with GCC etc.). So execution won't start at all.

Answer (score 1):

The ELF file format is the same. The difference is the file paths embedded in the ELF file.

ELF is a very general format, which can encode many things about the contents of a file. Linux, Android, and many other operating systems use ELF format for executables and libraries but that does not make them compatible. It's like having directions for different journeys by road. They're all written in the same language (corresponding to ELF) but trying to follow directions for getting to Koln from Stuttgart when you're starting in Frankfurt won't work.

As per the comments, if you build a *completely* statically linked executable for x86-64 it may well work both in the Android emulator and on your Linux desktop. However, most programs need to use system libraries, and the linker embeds the names of those libraries, and the path to the run-time linker in your ELF executables.

Although Android uses a Linux kernel, the system libraries and run-time linker are completely different from Linux. Android uses the [Bionic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bionic_(software)) library, and most Linuxes use [glibc](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glibc). This was deliberate: Android was originally designed for fairly slow devices without much RAM, and needed a library that didn't take up much space and ran quickly. Glibc could assume more powerful hardware.

The Android run-time linker is `/system/bin/linker` (or `/system/bin/linker64` for 64-bit code). The Linux run-time linker is *usually* `/lib/ld.so` (or `/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2` for 64-bit code). Obviously, these are different paths, and each only exists on the relevant operating system. The "file not found" error you get when running an Android ELF file on Linux is a complaint that `/system/bin/linker64` doesn't exist on your Linux system.